# Recovering Images from .write to file in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to recover an image from .write to file.

Here's the code I used to save it:

```
view.pdfData.writeToURL(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf"), atomically: true) 
        view.pdfData.writeToFile("test", atomically: false)
        print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path!)
```

and here's how I'm trying to recover it :

```
 let path: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "pdf", inDirectory: "DirectoryName/Images")
        let imageFromPath = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)!
        self.imageview.image = imageFromPath
```

But I keep getting a breakpoint :

[the breakpoint I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjyFk.png)

Niall

Comment: What do you expect? The application bundle and the documents directory are completely different locations.

Comment: @vadian The breakpoint is on a different line when I change the inDirectory.  http://postimg.org/image/hwirk8tcn/

Comment: Again, what do you expect? You cannot read files written in `Documents` from the application bundle. And don't "hard code" paths.

Comment: @vadian is there any way to save it to a different location as I need to be able to recover the image.

Comment: Recover the file from the location where it's written to: Get the `URLsForDirectory` and append the file name, the same procedure as in the writing routine.

Comment: Where should I change? @vadian

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the path for reading the same way you do for writing. Using `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource` will look for a resource in the app bundle the was installed with the app.

```
let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf").path
let imageFromPath = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)!
```

---

As an aside, force unwrapping optionals using `!` is generally a bad idea. It doesn't allow your app to gracefully handle getting a nil value and will cause a crash (like the one you posted). The proper way would be like this.

```
if let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first,
    let path = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf").path,
    let imageFromPath = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
        print("Loaded Image")
} else {
    print("Unable to load image")
}
```

Comment: I get a print out of "Unable to load image" It's not able to find the image even though I've saved it as"test.pdf"

Comment: I read png instead of pdf. pdf is not a file type the [UIImage supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW3).

Comment: Even when I change it saving and recovering as a png, It's "Unable to load image"

Comment: @NiallKehoe You need to use QLPreviewController() to open your pdf or a webview

Comment: @NiallKehoe another option is to save a snapshot from your view

Comment: I did a tutorial on QLPreviewController and it seems good. Here's a screen shot of what I've tried to implement: . The line I've selected is the one I would like to change to let imageFromPath = QLPreviewController() @LeoDabus

Comment: But how would i set the path?

Comment: @NiallKehoe `func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
return url
}`

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/za5i5rlcd/ @LeoDabus How would I set the path = to where I saved the image with .write to file?